# Elemento de lista a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt4

estoy intentando pasar datos de una lista a un **QTableWidget** la lista contiene lo siguiente:

```
[['0.6545454545454545', '67'], ['0.6486486486486487', '14'], ['0.6136363636363636', '38']]
```

el código que intento es el siguiente:

```
  fila=0
    for registro in range (NC):
        columna=0
        self.dialogo.TablaResul.insertRow(fila)
        for elemento in range(NC):
            celda=QTableWidgetItem(elemento)
            self.dialogo.TablaResul.setItem(fila,columna,celda)
            columna+=1
        fila+=1
```

Donde **NC** es la cantidad de datos a mostrar, pero con ese codigo solo genero las filas y columnas pero los datos no los inserta.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que esto te ayude:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QAction, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 tabla'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.createTable()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Mostrar Widget

        self.show()

    def createTable(self):
        data = [['0.6545454545454545', '67'], ['0.6486486486486487',
                '14'], ['0.6136363636363636', '38']]
        f = len(data)  # No. de filas
        c = len(data[0])  # No. de columnas

       # Crea Tabla

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(f)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(c)

        for i in range(f):
            for j in range(c):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j,
                        QTableWidgetItem(data[i][j]))
        self.tableWidget.move(0, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]